# SGH-T989 (UVLDH firmware) Goes into Recovery mode, but not Download

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-2, twrp, linux, heimdall, t-mobile

I'm trying to get my SGH-T989 into Download mode so I can flash TWRP with heimdal. It's been awhile since I've done this and from what I recall (and have researched a bit) I need to:

- unplug cable
- power off
- hold **Vol_Down** + **Vol_UP**
- plug in cable

This isn't working though. All I get is [recovery mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zYt1S.jpg) and what I want is [Download mode](https://cromwell-intl.com/technical/samsung-galaxy/pictures/cyanogenmod-4019.jpg).

Not sure if the device/cable/PC is bad. Using Linux. Tried a 14.04 box and a 16.04. What have I missed?. Been googling, but lots of mixed info. Anyone help?
Thanks

----- update ----------
 [image: update with pic of dongle I purchased:]

Comment: You probably need a special dongle like [this one](https://www.amazon.com/Dongle-Download-Samsung-SPH-L710-Unbrick/dp/B01HQ0L730).

Comment: Thank you. I have seen this referenced in a few posts on XDA but why would it be needed (I *did* just pick the phone up off Ebay) ?

Comment: Odin itself is intended only for authorized repairsmen/shops - makes sense that it once was not easily accessible. The dongle itself is just a resistor in essence though so you can make one yourself if you're up for it.

Comment: Thanks again for taking the time to answer. I ordered one but soon after, remembered I had purchased a dock for this phone off Ebay months ago. Only fits if the phone case is removed so never used it. Thought I'd try it while waiting for the dongle to show up. It worked to get into download mode! Maybe it's a resister built in the dock or something? I must have tried 3 different USB cables which have all worked with other phones in the past.  One cable even worked yesterday with a friend's SGH-T989. Soooo baffling.

Comment: Awesome. I'll put it into a formal answer for you to accept.

Comment: Added pic of usb jigs I purchased in case anyone else stumbles across this. Picked up  another  sgs2 and ended up using the jig on it. Worked great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Older Samsung devices might require a special USB dongle/jig like [this one](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01HQ0L730) to trigger Odin mode - just plug it in when the device is powered off. It's essentially a resistor between USB pins so you can also make one yourself if you're up for it.